# How do two Tor relays communicate with one another?

Tags: tor

Nodes don't know each other's IP address right?

So how do they manage to address one another when it comes to sending data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually every Tor nodes knows the IP address of any other node in the network. Assuming you have a fresh install of Tor, upon start it downloads a list of *all* current relays in the network. The file `cached-microdesc-consensus` in Tor's data directory contains lines like:

> r CrytoDotNet4 APEqsDXWLJGaHzfCpnFE8XrMnnU 2014-04-18 12:08:46 **88.150.203.212** 9001 9030
>      m CyN/m3Q80Q0ow2folHfEBqZkL9zKJvkeOpJpzqjoN5s
>      s Fast HSDir Named Running Stable V2Dir Valid

As you can see this file contains the IP addresses.

Furthermore the Tor Project keeps a database of old Tor relays. So if you want to find out if a specific IP address was a Tor relay in the past you can visit the [exonerator page](https://exonerator.torproject.org/), enter some information and get an answer.

For further questions on Tor I'd recommend to visit the [Tor StackExchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/) site. You'll find some more answers there.

Answer (score 3):

They do know eachother's IP address. Tor works so that every relay node knows the previous and the next hop. However they never know the full route.